# Sorting/Displaying a large data set within a browser - how much JSON is too much?

Tags: json, sorting, browser, pagination

This is a technical question regarding browser limitations for parsing and sorting JSON.

We are looking at performing a clustering algorithm on large data sets (potentially 50k rows, potentially 10 fields per row) that are returned from a query and displayed to users in a table, 25 rows per page, and sortable on all fields.  The clustering will take place server side and then send back the client the clustered results as JSON.

Currently, the clustered result data will not be existing within any database table. This creates some issues for sorting and paging, and back button support too.

Instead of rerunning the query for "next page" and "resort", I'm wondering if I could send all the data back at one time as a potentially very large JSON, and then displaying only 25 records at a time to implement paging.  But what about when a user wants to resort?  Could a browser handle resorting 50k+ rows?  And still maintain the paging feature?

Would it just be better to create a temp table for the users query results?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but with my Mozilla hat on, I think this is something that we would *like* to be fast, and if it's slow - especially if it's slow with Firefox 4 betas - we would like to hear from you.

Comment: Hey, I tried testing this out by creating some dummy data, and the results weren't good. For the dummy json data I created, each record contained 4 attributes, total characters for all attributes was 175 per record.  Clusters contained seven records, plus one to display as cluster summary.  For 1000 clusters this creates a json file sized 1.7 Mb.  There would be the potential for users to receive results of 18.5k clusters, resulting in ~31 Mb of json data.
The max size json file i could open in the browser was 8 Mb. ...too much json... going to go temp tables in a db I think.

Answer (score 0):

you might get a faster result with jsonp.  I don't know if there any limits on size, other than practical, since you basically make the browser treat the json as a script.  You would have to process the result into some sort of data structure to support your paging, but that shouldn't be difficult.